# Algorithm for QP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

Let $\mathbb{Q}^+ = \{ q \in \mathbb{Q} : q > 0 \}$.
For $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$, let $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$, $b_1, \dots, b_{n} \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ and $c_1, \ldots, c_n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Define $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ as $$f (x_1, \dots, x_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n (a_i - x_i)^2$$

Suppose we want to minimize $f$ subject to the following constraints:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n b_i x_i = d \text{, where $d\in \mathbb{Q}$  } \tag{LC}$$

$$x_i \geqslant c_i  \text{ for all integers } 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n \tag{LB}$$

---

**Algorithm**

To solve this, I am currently using the following recursive algorithm:

Take Arguments: Objective, Linear Constraint, Lower Bounds

1. minimize Objective subject to Linear Constraint only (using Lagrangian)
2. if solution to (1.) satisfies Lower Bounds, return this solution
3. otherwise, for each variable $x_i$ in Objective do the following:

   1. substitute $x_i = c_i$ into Linear Constraint and Lower Bounds

      call the results LC($i$) and LB($i$) respectively
   2. substitute $x_i = c_i$ into Objective, call the result O($i$)
   3. Apply Algorithm with

      Objective = O($i$), Linear Constraint = LC($i$) and Lower Bound = LB($i$)
4. from solutions given by (3.), return the solution giving the smallest Objective

I run this algorithm with Objective = $f$, Linear Constraint = LC and Lower Bound = LB. Essentially, this minimizes without the LB constraint, and if that doesn't work, it “searches along the border” by substituting $x_i = c_i$ for each $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$ and minimizing this instead (w.r.t. the remaining variables).

---

**Questions**

1. Does this algorithm work (i.e. give the correct minimum)?
2. Is there a faster way to find the minimum? (see below)

---

**Context**

I'm using Python (specifically SymPy) to find the *exact* minimum for this problem. Although there are much faster numerical algorithms, those aren't exact. I'm limited to methods available in Sympy (e.g., can't do symbolic minimization directly, but can solve equations) but am happy to implement any methods suggested here.

Comment: If I understand well, you substitute $x_i=c_i$ for **one $i$** not several? Right? If it is the case, I suspect that you'll miss true minimum in some cases.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is a [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming?wprov=sfla1) one.

Comment: What leads you to the assumption that the exact minimum of the quadratic program can be found?

Comment: Why use SymPy rather than CVXPY?

Comment: Why do you need the exact minimum? That is an interesting specification.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes, one $i$ at a time, and do it for each $i$. could you please give an example where the minimum is not found?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo sorry, I'd forgotten some conditions on the parameters. specifically the $b_i$s are positive, so the constraints give a closed and bounded space where a minimum must exist

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo no particular reason for Sympy, if there's better way in CVXPY then I'd be happy to use that too

Comment: @rodie9k Well, CVXPY can only give you a `float`-valued solution. Might be useful to verify the symbolic solution nonetheless.

Comment: You forgot to introduce $d$ in the 1st paragraph.